# Showing deleted integers topology not locally path connected

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Why is the deleted integer topology not locally path connected? It is listed in the book "counterexamples in topology"

However, I cannot seem to find a point which is not locally path connected since each point $p$ is in some open set which contain the intervals $p \in(n-1,n)$ and it is always path connected.

Comment: How is this topology defined?

Comment: Hi the deleted integer topology is defined in the link shown: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Deleted_Integer_Topology

Comment: This space is locally path connected. Why do you think it is not? The book of counterexamples doesn´t mention whether it is or not locally path connected.

Comment: But by Figure 8 of page 30 of the book, doesn't it list the deleted integer topology as one which is local connected but not Connected, local path connected etc? Sorry for the trivial question as it's the first time I am using the book.

Comment: You are right, I had not seen figure 8, I was just looking at the body of the example in page 43. But figure 8 only says it is not connected, path connected, arc connected or hyperconnected; it does not mention locally pathconnected. Note also that the chart in pages 194-195 is not filled for the deleted integers, I assume because it has the same values as the odd-even topology. In particular, it should have a 1 under "locally path connected".

Comment: Hi, do you mean the chart on 199 instead? The chart on Figure 8 talks about local connectedness that overlaps with path connectedness, and could the region where the local connectedness overlaps with path connectedness signifies local path connectedness? (I Couldn't prove that the topology listed is local path connectedness if that is the case)